# Laravel Dusk: Failed to connect to localhost port 9515

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

Suddenly Laravel Dusk fails to connect to the local server.
Connecting to remote server still works.
Using current macOS.

**Error message**

```
   PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper 

  Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1920,1080","--disable-gpu"]}}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1920,1080","--disable-gpu"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

  at vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:346
    342▕             if (is_array($params) && !empty($params)) {
    343▕                 $msg .= sprintf(' with params: %s', json_encode($params, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
    344▕             }
    345▕ 
  ➜ 346▕             throw new WebDriverCurlException($msg . "\n\n" . $error);
    347▕         }
    348▕ 
    349▕         $results = json_decode($raw_results, true);
    350▕ 



  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   0.24s
```

Local server start-up before running the test with Laravel Dusk:

```
➜  php artisan serve

   INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].  

  Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
```

Uninstalling and re-installing doesn't help.
Also tried other things without success, see: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/1016

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by adding the lines

```
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
uses(DuskTestCase::class);
```

to the test file or by updating *Pest.php* as discussed [here](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/1017).